# Filter two values in array of objects

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, contains

I have an array of objects and I want to filter them by two conditions, either if object is in an certain group or if it has an certain name but I can not figure out why it is not working.

This is my code:

```
let outputfiler = array.filter({$0.group.contains (where: {$0 == "groupBig" }) } || $1.name.contains(where: {$1 == "Eis"})  )
```

This is the error I get:

> Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure

Edit:
Group is an array of trings,
name just a string.

I also tried this:

```
outputfiler = array.filter{$0.group.contains (where: {$0 == "groupBig" }) || $0.name(where: {$0 == "Eis"}) }
```

But then I get this error:

```
Extraneous argument label 'where:' in call
```

Comment: Filter takes a single closure, you can have multiple boolean expressions within the closure. So start by ensuring your array.filter is followed by { rather than (.

Comment: I did the changes you suggested but does not work

Comment: if name is a `String` property, `$0.name(where:)` doesn't really make sense. Are you trying to test if contains the substring "Eis" or is equal to "Eis"? In the latter case, use `array.filter{ $0.group.contains("groupBig") || $0.name == "Eis" }`. In the former, `contains(where:)` only deals with `Character` so you need a different API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need your filter as follows (shown on multiple lines for clarity):

```
let outputfiler = array.filter({
    $0.group.contains(where: { $0 == "groupBig" }) || 
    $0.name.contains("Eis")
})
```

You had the filter's closing `}` before the `||`. And assuming `name` is a `String`, `contains` just takes the string to search, not a closure.

Comment: i tried this but xcode tells me "Extraneous argument label 'where:' in call" i should delete the secont "where".

Comment: Is `name` a `String` or an array of `String`? See the update that assumes it is a `String` and not an array.

Comment: yes thanks sorry my fault, yes group was an array of strings and name just an string. It works now, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This syntax should work.

```
let outputfiler = array.filter{$0.group.contains("groupBig") || $0.name.contains("Eis")}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in Swift 5 (Example ):

My struct (I use this struct for extract data from Firebase):

```
struct User { 

    let uid:String
    let phoneNumber:String
    let username:String
    let email:String

    init(uid:String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? String()
        self.phoneNumber = dictionary["phoneNumber"] as? String ?? String()
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? String()

    }

}
```

Filter:

```
let arrayFiltered =  self.arrayUsers.filter { (user) -> Bool in
    return user.username.lowercased().contains("Dani".lowercased()) ||
           user.email.lowercased().contains("DanielXXXX@gmail.com".lowercased()) ||
           user.phoneNumber.lowercased().contains("+34111223344".lowercased())

}
```

Have a good day ♥️.